# Finite Field Multiplication Confusion

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let's assume we are dealing with a GF($2^8$) - not necessarily related to the AES algorithm. It seems that the steps to perform multiplication of two elements of the field are:

1) multiply the polynomials as usual

2) divide the result with an irreducible polynomial from the field

How do I know which one of the irreducible polynomials to use? The necklace formula suggest that there are many. Is there a difference when using different irreducible polynomials? If so, do we then have many possible multiplication operators for the field? If not, why is there no difference?

Also, it seems that the multiplicative inverse is defined only once - is it somehow tied to a specific irreducible polynomial?

And a last, possibly related question: when I see *field defined by a irreducible polynomial* - is that perhaps tied to choosing a particular multiplication function?

Comment: We have that $\;GF(2^8)\cong \Bbb F_2[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ , with $\;f(x)\in\Bbb F_2[x]\;$ irreducible of degree eight. Find $\;f\;$ and you'll know by what polynomial to divide.

Comment: The irreducible polynomial of degree 3 you choose will determine how you multiply, in kind of the same way that a choice of basis determines what your matrices look like, if you're working in a vector space. But no matter what polynomial you choose, you'll always get a field which has an equivalent addition/multiplication table to any other field created in the same way, with a different irred poly of degree 3. (However the bijection is somewhat mysterious to write down explicitly)